# fetchRequest is return empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to fetch Request from my DB. but i am getting nil in the response. The fetch is ok because when i use this method i am getting "sometimes" Values. (i know that i have data in the DB ). i think that this is somehow related to threads issue or because i am using Multi-Context. So my Question is basically generic.

1. if i am saving some data in specific MOC let's call it MOC1 and then i want to fetch that data that i just save .. i can use any MOC ? ( assuming that i save the child and parent and i can see the change on the DB )
2. if i save data with MOC that use NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType can i fetch with MOC NSMainQueueConcurrencyType? and the opposite way.. ?
3. i can fetch data on background thread or i have to fetch on the main Thread?
4. what is the connection between the Main thread and NSMainQueueConcurrencyType
5. what is the connection between the Background thread and NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType 
   Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

The thing is that i fetch some entity and change some flag to isSync = YES when i want to save it i use my save method:

```
-(void)saveDataToDBWithCompletionWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext withCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded ,NSError *error))completion {
if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *errorMsg = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&errorMsg]) {
            // do some real error handling
            NSLog(@"couldn't save Background Context, error %@, %@", errorMsg, [errorMsg userInfo]);
            if (completion) {
                completion(NO, errorMsg);
            }
        } else {
            if (completion) {
                completion(YES, nil);
            }
        }
    }];
} else {
    if (completion) {
        completion(NO, nil);
    }
}
```

}

This method get the NSManagedObjectContext, and save it in to the relevant NSManagedObjectContext. then i run my master save:

```
-(void)saveMasterDataToDBWithSync:(BOOL)toDoSync WithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded ,NSError *error))completion {
NSError *errorMsg = nil;
if (self.masterManagedObjectContext != nil) {
    if ([self.masterManagedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![self.masterManagedObjectContext save:&errorMsg]) {
        if (completion) {
            completion(NO, errorMsg);
        }
    } else {
        if (toDoSync) {
          // DO sync with Parse
        }

        if (completion) {
            completion(YES, nil);
        }
    }
} else {
    if (completion) {
        completion(NO, nil);
    }
}
```

}

When i check my DB the data is there! but when i will try to fetch it i can not see any thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. But you need to find a way to notify that MOC about the changes you made. You can do that by using a child/parent context (`parentContext`), by saving to the `persistentStoreCoordinator` or by merging changes using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`. In any case you must `save` for the changes to propagate.
2. Yes. Same as #1.
3. You can fetch on whichever thread you wish as long as you use the thread/queue associated with this MOC. You can do that by using `performBlock` or just making sure your running a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and calling the fetch from the main thread.
4. `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` should run only on the main thread.
5. `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` has its own private queue. Use `performBlock` to run the fetch on that queue.

Comment: Hey Thanks!!!  about 1. you mean that i i save some thing with MOC1 ( save also with the Master MOC , and it's on the DB ) i need to inform the other MOC, MOC2, that need to fetch ?